# Image not preloading in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to detect if an image has been preloaded by the browser in some integration tests I'm writing and I have this issue.

When I run `phantomjs` on this script (event with the option `--load-images=true`)

```
"use strict";

// This code is returning twice false on phantom !
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://96pix.com/images/tambakothejaguar_2.jpg';
console.log(image.complete);
setTimeout(function(){
    var image2 = new Image();
    image.src = 'http://96pix.com/images/tambakothejaguar_2.jpg';
    console.log(image.complete);
}, 1000);
```

It is returning `false` twice witch is not the behavior I'm witnessing when I run the script on Chrome on Firefox since I've got (as expected) `false` then `true`

Is their an option on phantomjs I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with a higher threshold like `4000`

Comment: I'm not sure why you have `image2` in your code, because you're never using it.

Comment: I agree with @ArtjomB., the `image2` variable is not used. If I change `image` inside `setTimeout` to `image2`, the output is `false`, then `true`.

Comment: You're right that was a typo and with `image2` inside the setTimeout it works on phantomjs, but that's weird because with the typo it still works on chrome and FF that seems to correctly modify the attribute `.complete` on `image` afterwards as expected.